# How to make a diagonal LazyColumn with Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to make a scrollable list with images. I want to use LazyColumn because the list may be too big and I need it to manage the items showing. However, in my case, I want this list of items to be in a diagonal shape and I was hoping someone had an idea for this. Here is a visual representation of what I mean by a diagonal scrollable list:
[Scrollable diagonal list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHQoy.png)

I have tried messing with the modifier rotate but the results aren't great.